# How to get environment that have been set in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

In Jenkinsfile

No ideas why and how this simple code doesn't work.

```
node {
    environment {
        ENV_1 = 'value1'
    }
    env.ENV_2 = 'value2'

    echo "${env.ENV_1}" // not worked (null)
    echo "${env.ENV_2}" // worked (value2)

}
```

Does `environment{}` work the save way of `env.VAR = xx`?

edited: Is it related that I'm using with **pipline** not **multibranchs pipeline**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `environment` closure is for [jenkins-declarative-pipeline](/questions/tagged/jenkins-declarative-pipeline).

In scripted pipelines, use the [`withEnv`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-withenv-code-set-environment-variables) closure/step to define the scope of an env var:

```java
node {
  withEnv(['ENV_1=value2']) {
    echo env.ENV_1
  }
}
```

Comment: Awww, I tough we can mix between declarative and scripted pipelines. Both syntax are so similar.. and done without any exception. So bad:(

Comment: Well, the syntax is the difference ;-)